# What criteria does google check to see which files require the new resourceKey?

Tags: google-drive-api

Google recently announced that to access certain files on google drive my application should use a resouceKey along with the fileId when trying to access google drive through Api. When I checked the files in my google drive I find that not all files have the new resourceKey. I uploaded a new file and that too does not have the new resourceKey.
This lead me to wonder as to what criteria should a file satisfy to be requiring the new resourceKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the `resourceKey` is required for users who have not been shared the file specifically with them (that is, files shared with `Anyone with the link` or `Anyone in the domain`, but not shared with that user specifically) and which haven't accessed that file previously.

Because of this, files that you own, files that you have accessed before, and files that have been shared with you specifically don't require a `resourceKey`.

You can check the details of the impacted files on the [alert center](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9105276).

#### Reference:

- [Update to some Google Drive file links, admin decision recommended before July 23, 2021](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/06/drive-file-link-updates.html)
- [Decide how to apply link-sharing security update to Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685032)
- [Access link-shared files using resource keys](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys)